# How to add flag to kubelet

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-rook

I want to deploy rook for kubernetes. I use 1 master and 3 worker and the host is ubuntu in baremetal. but the container stuck in creating container. after a lot of search i understand i should use this document https://github.com/rook/rook/blob/master/Documentation/flexvolume.md#most-common-readwrite-flexvolume-path that said

> Configuring the Rook operator You must provide the above found
>   FlexVolume path when deploying the rook-operator by setting the
>   environment variable FLEXVOLUME_DIR_PATH. For example:
>
> env: [...]
>   - name: FLEXVOLUME_DIR_PATH   value: "/var/lib/kubelet/volumeplugins" (In the operator.yaml manifest replace  with the
>   path or if you use helm set the agent.flexVolumeDirPath to the
>   FlexVolume path)
>
> Configuring the Kubernetes kubelet You need to add the flexvolume flag
>   with the path to all nodes's kubelet in the Kubernetes cluster:
>
> --volume-plugin-dir=PATH_TO_FLEXVOLUME (Where the PATH_TO_FLEXVOLUME is the above found FlexVolume path)

the question is how can i add  flexvolume flag with the path to all nodes's kubelet ?

Answer (score 2):

@yasin lachini,
If you deploy kubernetes cluster on baremetal, you don't need to configure anything. That is because /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/ is the kubelet default FlexVolume path and Rook assumes the default FlexVolume path if not set differently.

My env:
rook-ceph/operator.yml (use default FLEXVOLUME_DIR_PATH) :

```
...
        # Set the path where the Rook agent can find the flex volumes
        # - name: FLEXVOLUME_DIR_PATH
        #   value: "/usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec"
...
```

After deploy,on node:

```
# ls /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/
ceph.rook.io~rook  ceph.rook.io~rook-ceph-system  rook.io~rook  rook.io~rook-ceph-system
```

Comment: i think you are right but why my pod does not created an i get this error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442548/failed-to-mount-volume-dev-rbd1-xfs
i will very thankful if you look at it

Comment: Let's go there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

**I**. set

```
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--FLEXVOLUME_DIR_PATH=/var/lib/kubelet/volumeplugins
```

within the file

```
/etc/default/kubelet
```

And restart kubelete service

```
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

**II**. You can set kubelet parameters via a config file.

For example:

```
kind: KubeletConfiguration
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
env:
- name: FLEXVOLUME_DIR_PATH
  value: "/var/lib/kubelet/volumeplugins"
```

Then, you just start the Kubelet with the --config flag set to the path of the Kubelet’s config file

```
sudo kubelet --config=/etc/default/kubelet/custom-conf.config
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/

Comment: i do not have /etc/default/kubelet

Comment: do you know about rook?

Comment: @yasinlachini file should be on your master node. I'm not familiar with rook, sorry

Comment: i check it in master and  /etc/default/kubelet does not exist

Comment: what version of kubelet do you use?

Comment: my version is v1.14.0

Comment: Did you try with second option?

Comment: @yasinlachini regarding the Linux distribution you are using, the kubelet file you are looking for can be in `/etc/sysconfig/kubelet`

Answer (score 0):

If you initiated your Cluster with kubeadm you can add flags in this file: `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env` and then restart the kubelet with `sudo systemctl restart kubelet`